# .NET SQL Server Connection by name and IP differs in behavior

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, web, asp.net-web-api

Not sure if this is a StackOverflow question, but we hit this really strange problem with our ASP.NET 4 web app.
So, there is a typical connection string to SQL Server with Data Source specified in web.config.

SQL Server is run on VM on the same host as Web VM runs. They are in one network. If we specify connection using VM name, like "sql-server-vm", the web app works properly without any issues. But if we specify IP address of SQL Server VM instead, we start running into transient issues, like long server answers or timeouts.

Trying tracert the IP from the Web server VM shows the proper IP, so it's definitely the same machine and it is avaliable by name and IP. We are using ASP.NET Web API 2, ADO.NET, SQL Server 2014 SP3 in this project.

Is it possible that connection using ADO.NET does not properly work with IP address, but works with SQL Server Instance name? I cannot imagine a reason for this, but this is clearly what happens.

Comment: Do you specify a sql instance in the ip address? and more so and most important is are you running the browser service for sql service? SQL on startup is assigned a internal IP address, and the browser service translates that internal IP to a external one based on the SQL "instance". That's how multiple instances of sql server can be run, and be run on the same IP address. So the sql browser service is what does this translating for you. And if your instance of sql server is not the default instance, then again IP address can cause issues. If you specify IP\SQLINSTANCE then IP should work fine

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thank you for the idea! As I can see Browser Service is disabled. Do you think that without it enabled the issue described still can happen and it makes sense to try IP\SQLINSTANCE solution?

Comment: yes, the browser service is in most cases required - it will translate the IP address (internatl) assigned to the instance of sql server to the machines IP address. In past, sql server was assigned the same IP address as the computer - this is not the case (anymore), and thus without the browser service running, you often can't even use servername\sqlinstance either. So even with IP or servername being used, you in most cases now need to run the sql browser service. start the browser service and always run it.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I have checked our another server where we did not encounter any problems. It does not have Browser Service enabled as well. Both servers run one SQL Server instance. I have checked with `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')` them both and they are both Default. Considering the fact that the problem is transient on one server (i.e. some requests work, some other do not), do you think that this could still be Browser Service issue? I'm just hesitant before enabling it, do not want to cause any issues:)

Comment: Its only one thing to check and try. Not 100% sure this would be your issue - since you are able to connect (I assume) most of the time. So this is more of a long shot. The default instance with later versions of sql server now often need the browser service - try connecting with SSMS 18.x or later - you see now it don't connect unless browser service is running. Hey, maybe there is a some other code execution error - that's causing your app pool to re-cycle and session vars are blown out. We had so many issues we adopted sql server session - all problems gone as a result (no app re-cycle).